# Swift 3 Reachability From Button

Tags: swift, reachability

I am using the Reachability library on github found [here](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift). I want to check whether device is online by clicking on a button. I am new to Reachability so from what I have seen, you have to start listening for the change and then test the connection and then stop listening. So far I have this in my button action but when I click the button, nothing gets printed to console.

```
var reachability: Reachability!
do {
    try reachability?.startNotifier()
} catch {
    print("Unable to start notifier")
}


reachability?.whenReachable = { reachability in

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }
    }
}


reachability?.whenUnreachable = { reachability in

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("Not reachable")
    }
}


reachability?.stopNotifier()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `nil` because of using implicitly unwrapped optional.

Replace,

```
var reachability: Reachability!
```

to

```
let reachability = Reachability()
```

Try below,

```
let reachability = Reachability()

do {
    try reachability?.startNotifier()
} catch {
    print("Unable to start notifier")
}


if reachability?.isReachable == true{

    if reachability?.isReachableViaWiFi == true{
        print("Reachable via WiFi")
    } else if reachability?.isReachableViaWWAN == true{
        print("Reachable via WWAN simulator")
    }else{
        print("Reachable via Cellular")
    }

}else{
    print("Not reachable")
}


reachability?.stopNotifier()
```

Comment: When I hit the button once it prints "Reachable via WiFi" but if I click the button again nothing happens. Can reachability only be checked once?

Comment: That worked. Why does this version work but my original version only print out once?

Comment: @Martheli , Most of the time the original version also worked like this. First time only not working. Also can't able to catch why that time not working. Because, Again not have that kinda of issue when using original version. May be if flag changes then it will be work.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `reachability?.stopNotifier()` inside the main thread block

Comment: Now I am getting `unexpectedly found nil` on `try reachability.startNotifier()`